# SQL Server Change Tracking keeps going back to FALSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-tracking

In our Microsoft SQL Server, the Change Tracking in each table in our database keeps going back to FALSE. We've changed it back to TRUE twice now. How come this happens and what can we do to prevent it?

Comment: When you say that "Change Tracking in each table in our database keeps going back to FALSE" are you talking about SQL Server 2019 Change Tracking (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and that its reverting back to disabled at the table level as if this command was being run `ALTER TABLE Person.Contact DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;` ?

Comment: Hi @JeffMergler thats correct. Whenever we add a new table in the database, all tables in that database revert back to CHANGE TRACKING FALSE. We have to keep re-running our script: ALTER TABLE Person.Contact  
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)

Comment: @Judy Do you have a DBA? (if so, have you asked them about this?) Where is this DB hosted? Are there any DDL Triggers or system policy settings that reset the DB to some desired state every-so-often? Have you run an XEvents trace to find out who and when the `CHANGE_TRACKING` option is being changed?